# How to apply an effect on sprite in actionscript 3

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, effects

I have a sprite and I want to apply for example fade effect on it.
I found examples how to do it in flex ML but how can I do it in pure actionscript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I personally prefer [TweenMax](http://www.greensock.com/tweenmax/), but you can use the build in [Tween](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/fl/transitions/Tween.html) in Flash as well.

```
var myTweenAlpha:Tween = new Tween(myClip, "alpha", Strong.easeOut, 0, 1, 3, true);
```

Comment: Seems like I gotta go this way not mx.effects.fade

Comment: Good. I think you should look into using TweenMax if you want to use a lot of animations and effects.

Comment: Read an atricle recently about Greenstocks TweenLite, supposedly the fastest of the tweening api's. And no, I dont work for them:)

Answer (score 1):

Where are the examples that show you how to do it in MXML?

That said, effects are implemented using the style Mechanism.  So, to apply a fade effect on a UIComponent you'd do something like this:

```
MyUIComponent.setStyle('showEffect', myEffectClass);
```

Since the Flex effect stuff is implemented in UIComponent, and [Fade](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/effects/Fade.html) is a Flex effect, not a generic ActionScript effect, I do not believe there is any way to apply a fade effect to a Sprite.

Look at the [Sprite](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Sprite.html) docs; there are no effects listed.

Comment: I got it. Effects are only for uicomponents :(http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=charts_eventsandeffects_10.html